# How do I select text to the start or end of a line on a laptop without End/Home keys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, hp-elitebook

I have an EliteBook.

My understanding is that the keyboard shortcut for selecting text to the left/right is <kbd>Shift-Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-End</kbd> respectively. However, this keyboard does not have Home or End keys, so I have to use <kbd>Fn+Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Fn+Right Arrow</kbd>

Typing <kbd>Fn+Shift</kbd> activates fn lock. As a result typing <kbd>Fn+Shift+Right Arrow</kbd> does not result in selecting text to the right (or, in the case of Left, Up, or Down arrows, start of line, top of text, and bottom of text respectively).

Selecting text to the left and right seems like a pretty common thing people would want to do, so it seems like there must be some way of doing this on a laptop keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case, the answer is actually quite obvious once I stumbled across it.

Key order matters.

You have to type the keys in the order <kbd>Shift+Fn+Left</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Fn+Right</kbd>. Not sure why I was defaulting to <kbd>Fn+Shift</kbd> to start with but that was the cause of my issue.

So it works, you just have to type Shift before the Fn key instead of after.

Comment: Great answer.  and order does matter.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer, and order does matter.

If you press and hold <kbd>shift</kbd>, then press and hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and then press either <kbd>left arrow</kbd> for text `highlighted` to the <kbd>beginning of line</kbd> or <kbd>right arrow</kbd> for text `highlighted` to the <kbd>end of line</kbd>.

To avoid the `highlights`, press and hold <kbd>shift</kbd>, press and hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> key,  **then *let go* of <kbd>shift</kbd>**, and *then* press either <kbd>left arrow</kbd> to move to the <kbd>beginning of line</kbd> or <kbd>right arrow</kbd> to move to the <kbd>end of line</kbd>.